# Sell specifying the "total" instead of the "amount" parameter

Tags: coinbase-api

According to the ["Place sell order" documentation](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#place-sell-order), you can either use `amount` as parameter, or `total`:

```
amount  string  Required    Sell amount
total   string  Optional    Sell amount with fees (alternative to amount)
```

Using the Ruby client, I made a call

```
  client.sell(account.id,{
      "total" => some_value,
      "currency" => "ETH",
      "payment_method" => fiat_payment_method_id
    });
```

to sell some ETH back to USD. I got the following error message

```
.../lib/coinbase/wallet/api_client.rb:402:in `block in sell': Missing parameter: amount (Coinbase::Wallet::APIError)
```

Am I misreading the documentation ? Do I need to specify both account and total, and will the server use the total and ignore the amount ?

Or is the documentation just wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't realise the error was throwing by the Ruby code and not by the Coinbase server.
Looks like the code enforced the presence of the amount parameter.

Submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-ruby/pull/110) to get this fixed. Testing with my own local modified version of their gem indicates that the server works just fine with using "total" instead of "amount".